# jquery can't hide a form with an input name of "style"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide a form on a site, but it refuses to hide via jquery. I can manually set the style properties on the element, but `.hide()` does not hide it.

Consider this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').hide();    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input name="style_name" value="small" type="hidden">
    <p>I AM hidden</p>
</form>
    
<form>
    <input name="style" value="small" type="hidden">
    <p>I should be hidden</p>
</form>
```

Basically, if there is an input with a name of "style" it can't hide the form. If the input has a different name, it hides it just fine.

Is there a reason this is happening?

Comment: That's interesting...

Comment: yes it is ... because input names are copied to properties of the form object... the form.style is referring to the element now

Comment: the same problem exists when you have a input with name submit and if you try to submit a form using `form.submit()`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/s2q2a5am/2/ - look at the difference is the logged values - the style property of the second form is referring to the input element not the style object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "name" attributes of input elements in a form are used to populate properties on the form DOM node.  Your name, "style", overrides the "style" property of the form, which means that jQuery can no longer access the native style object. It needs to do that in order to hide the form.

Note that [you can still do this with CSS.](http://jsfiddle.net/ak89c996/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').addClass("hidden");    
});
```

CSS:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

Those old habits of implicitly trampling over namespaces dates from the early days of browser technology. It's hard to imagine anyone thinking it's a good idea nowadays, at least without there being some qualified sub-space (like `form.fields` or something).

Comment: this is sounding right, but can you elaborate a bit more? i'm unclear how when you try to alter the "style" of the form, that it ends up getting confused with a child input element?

Comment: @meesterfox every DOM node has a property called "style" that lets you access and modify the CSS styles directly on the element. It corresponds to what you'd put in the HTML "style": `<form style="width: 300px" ...>` or whatever. To hide the element, jQuery needs to do something like `theForm.style.display = "hidden";` but it can't because your `<input>` element's name caused that property to be overwritten.